# Lifting a function with another function as an argument in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, collections, monads, lifting

So I have a function in Haskell that I've simplified for the purpose of asking this question:

```hs
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Set

myFn :: Int -> Set Int
myFn a
  | a <= 0 = singleton 1
  | otherwise = foldMap helper (myFn (a - 1))

helper :: Int -> Set Int
helper a = insert (a + 2) (singleton a)

main :: IO ()
main = print . Data.Set.toList $ myFn 5
```

I want to have `myFn`'s dependency on `helper` to be put into a `Reader`, since inversion of control allows me to switch implementations in my tests:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Set

data MyEnv = MyEnv { helper' :: Int -> Set Int }
type MyReader = Reader MyEnv

myFn :: Int -> MyReader (Set Int)
myFn a
  | a <= 0 = return $ singleton 1
  | otherwise = do
      myFn' <- myFn (a - 1)
      helper'' <- asks helper'
      return (foldMap helper'' myFn')

helper :: Int -> Set Int
helper a = insert (a + 2) (singleton a)

main :: IO ()
main =
  let
    myEnv = MyEnv helper
  in
    print . Data.Set.toList $ runReader (myFn 5) myEnv
```

This works fine, except I don't like these three lines in particular:

```hs
myFn' <- myFn (a - 1)
helper'' <- asks helper'
return (foldMap helper'' myFn')
```

I feel like there should be a way to lift `foldMap` in the same way as `mapM` is a lifted version of `map` through its composition with `sequence`. Ideally, I would like those three lines to collapse down to one:

```hs
foldMapM helper'' (partitions (n - 1))
```

Assuming that: `helper'' :: Int -> MyReader (Set Int)`

This would of course require a `foldMapM` function with a signature similar to:

```hs
foldMapM
  :: (Monad m, Foldable t, Monoid n)
  => (a -> m n)
  -> m (t a)
  -> m n
```

I have tried so many things, but I just cannot seem to implement this function, though! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you would like to create `Monad m => m a -> m b -> m c` from `a -> b -> c`. That's exactly what [`liftM2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2) (from `Control.Monad`) does:

> ```
> liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
> ```
>
> Promote a function to a monad, scanning the monadic arguments from
>   left to right. For example,
>
> ```
> liftM2 (+) [0,1] [0,2] = [0,2,1,3]
> liftM2 (+) (Just 1) Nothing = Nothing
> ```

Therefore, it's as simple as using `liftM2 foldMap`:

```
myFn :: Int -> MyReader (Set Int)
myFn a
  | a <= 0    = return $ singleton 1
  | otherwise = liftM2 foldMap (asks helper') (myFn (a - 1))
```

Alternatively you can use `<$>` and `<*>` from `Control.Applicative` if you don't like additional parentheses:

```
myFn :: Int -> MyReader (Set Int)
myFn a
  | a <= 0    = return $ singleton 1
  | otherwise = foldMap <$> asks helper' <*> myFn (a - 1)
```

For more information, have a look at the [Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia).

Comment: Actually, `foldMapM f xs = liftM2 foldMap f xs` has signature `foldMapM :: (Monad m, Foldable t, Monoid n) => m (a -> n) -> m (t a) -> m n`. I tried this unsuccessfully before, since my function was of type `(a -> m n)`. I didn't think to do the `asks helper'` inline, though, to get `m (a -> n)`. This is perfect!